# Получить доступ к контексту из другого сервлета

Tags: spring

Разрабатываю приложение на Spring и Eclipse RAP. В рутовый контекст спринга добавить все бины не представляется возможным. Приложение падает с исключениями.
Поэтому некоторые бины вынесены в сервлет `appServlet`. Но вот `rwtServlet` ничего не знает про `appServlet`. Из-за этого не работает нормально DI. Как это можно исправить?

Файл **web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/site/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.eclipse.rap.applicationConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.HelloWorldConfiguration</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rwtServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rwtServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Пробовал получать рутовый контекст в `rwtServlet` а потом вручную догружать */WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml*. Так доступ к бинам получаю, но DI не работает.

Comment: а с какими исключениями падает приложение, если все бины в контекст добавить?

Comment: @zolt, ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context